# Jquery Onchange If else statement not working

Tags: jquery

I am getting problem with jquery onchange if else.
Here is code. This is not working with two if else statement.

```
jquery(".buildType").change(function() {
            var selectedvalue = $('.buildType').val();
            if (selectedvalue == 'Event launch kit') {
                jquery('.secondform').show();
                jquery('.eventTitle').next('.fieldError').remove();
            } else {
                jquery('.secondform').hide();
            }

            if (selectedvalue == 'Basic event without demand gen') {
                 jquery('.secondform').show();
                 jquery('.eventTitle').next('.fieldError').remove();
            } else {
                jquery('.secondform').hide();
            } 


        });
```

Do you have any solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: Show your HTML ?

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: Only First one condition is working. No console error

Comment: are you sure `selectedvalue == 'Basic event without demand gen'`

Comment: Yes this is same

Comment: what value you are getting from $('.buildType').val(); if you are getting this 'Event launch kit'  then only 1st condition will run

Comment: your `jquery` is not the proper case, I assume it is an alias for `jQuery`? or a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours is logical issue. You need to use `||` operator instead of 2 if blocks.

```
jquery(".buildType").change(function() {
    var selectedvalue = $(this).val();
    if (selectedvalue == 'Event launch kit' || selectedvalue == 'Basic event without demand gen') {
        jquery('.secondform').show();
        jquery('.eventTitle').next('.fieldError').remove();
    } else {
        jquery('.secondform').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be simpler with a conditional and just toggle the show and hide.  I made it slightly verbose to show what is going on.  It would be better to use the type in case another input has that class also as in this example.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("select.buildType").on('change', function() {
    let selectedvalue = $(this).val();
    let isLaunch = selectedvalue == 'Event launch kit';
    let isBasic = selectedvalue == 'Basic event without demand gen';
    let isAny = isLaunch || isBasic;
    $('.secondform').toggle(isAny);
    if (isAny) {
      $('.eventTitle').next('.fieldError').remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="buildType" value="notme" />
<div class="secondform">I am second</div>
<div class="eventTitle">cheese</div>
<div class="fieldError">I</div>
<div class="fieldError">Get</div>
<div class="fieldError">Removed</div>
<select class="buildType">
  <option value="Basic event without demand gen">Basic</option>
  <option value="Event launch kit">Launch</option>
  <option value="cheese">cheese</option>
</select>
```